# Purposes and differences between Magallanes, Travis, Jenkins, Ansible

Tags: jenkins, deployment, automation, ansible, travis-ci

I'm trying to get myself updated on workflow/deployment automation tools but the quantity is overwhelming and I cannot discern the differences of purposes of the multiple tools I'm finding.

So far the ones that I found interesting are:

[Magallanes:](https://magephp.github.io/)

**What I understood so far:** It's a deployment tool. Its purpose is to automatize deployment so you can get rid of most human errors and time to do the deployment.

[Travis:](https://travis-ci.org/)

**What I understood so far:** Continuous integration tool. It's used to automatize test integration on commit/deployment. But... can It automatize de deployment as well? Should I integrate it with Magallanes so Travis can manage the deployment with Magallanes?

[Jenkins:](https://jenkins.io/)

**What I understood so far:** Same as Travis but not as a service but as a tool you can configure and install instead. Same doubts, can I automatize deployments? just test integrations?

[Ansible:](https://jenkins.io/)

**What I understood so far:** Automatization of multiple tasks, deployment, sevice configuration management... I guess I can get rid of Magallanes and use Ansible, is this right? Can I integrate Ansible with Travis? or does travis also the Ansible deployment work (is the only automation I am interested at the moment)?

As you can see I'm lost here.

Wow: Already a close vote, where should I put this? It's a programming related question, they're programming related tools.

**Edit**: The thing is that I need to implement a deployment tool with the team and the projects I'm working on.

The doubts I do have are about, which tool should I be using (or which tools should I be integrate together). For example: I know Travis is for Test automation, but Can I use it for deployment? As I said, should I use it together with a more deployment oriented tool (Magallanes, or Ansible)... Maybe directly with Git?

The team was using Filezilla to upload things to production and SVN as a code sharing tool (no branches)... I was thinking of usin Git (server side, bye bye Filezilla) with hooks and a fine branch system but I know there're better ways and more complete deployment flows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Travis and Jenkins are both **continuous integration** tools.  Their primary purpose is to run your test suite on all commits, but some tools in this category can also trigger automatic deployments when the build is passing.  People writing code that needs to be compiled will sometimes talk about *build artifacts*, which are the things that can actually be deployed, but if you're using PHP, you're probably just doing a git pull or dropping a tarball on the server, so you don't need to be concerned with this aspect of CI tools.

I haven't heard of Magallanes before now, but yes, it appears to be a **deployment** tool.  Many companies create their own deploy tools for their specific situation, sometimes based on a tool like Capistrano or Fabric.

Ansible is a **configuration management** tool.  Primarily this is for managing configuration of your servers, but as a side benefit, since it knows about all your servers, it can also handle deploying new code to them.  Other popular tools in this category are Puppet, Chef, and Salt.

---

These tools are all about automation of pre-existing processes.  So, as you find a step that you're doing over and over again, go research what tool can be used to solve *that* problem; I find this to be a much better approach than to find the tools first and try to determine what problem of yours they can solve.

Comment: I edited the question, giving more info about what I'm trying to achive. Maybe you can specify a bit more the info.

Comment: I have opinions on what you should use for your deployment, but SO is trying to create canonical answers to problems and close opinion-based questions.  I find reddit to be a much better place for asking for advice on a specific situation; for this, I'd direct you to [r/devops](https://www.reddit.com/r/devops).

Comment: I will take your advice.